# Semantics and Coordination

Tags: syntax, semantics, coordination

Is coordination only governed by syntax?

What about sentences like "*I am afraid of and independent of him*"?
Is there nothing odd about it?

The coordinated element is a PP, so it conforms to Chomsky's generalisation but is it all there is about it?